# How to implement ALTER TABLE Query using Spring Data Jpa or Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Im inserting a CSV file in a database table using Spring Batch and Spring Data (and Hibernate).
each time I insert the CSV I have to delete the previous data in the table using the data-jpa deleteAll() method. the problem is that the ids of the table are incremented automatically and continuously  (@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)) after each delete/insert statement. 
I want that after each delete the ids start on 1. the only way that I found to do that is by altering the index (i know its not the best way, so your suggestions are welcomed) 
the Question is :
is there any method to run this SQL request

```
ALTER TABLE res AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

in Java object using Spring Data or Hibernate?
Thanks

Comment: For these kind of database migration you need to use flyway or liquidbase.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to generate id on java side and do not use embedded db autoincrement feature?

So the best way will be to generate id explicitly and set it to entity.

Other cases are:

Truncate Table

TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;

This will reset the auto increment on the table as well as deleting all records from that table.

Drop and Recreate

Table DROP TABLE table_name;

CREATE TABLE table_name { ... };

So I think, second is what are you looking for

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but this will impact all the logic of my code and relations between Entities.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I implemented another approach. see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Altering the table, I have customized the way that Hibernate Generates the Ids.

instead of using :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

I have implemented a custom id generator :

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_id", strategy = 
"com.xyz.utils.CustomIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                   @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                    name = "table_name", value = "myTable")
            })
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_id")
```

the  CustomIdGenerator class :

```
public class CustomIdGenerator  implements IdentifierGenerator,Configurable{

private    String  table_name ;

@Override
public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) 
        throws HibernateException {

    Connection connection = session.connection();

    try {
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select count(id) as Id from " 
    +table_name );

        if(rs.next())
        {
            int id=rs.getInt(1)+1;
            Integer generatedId = new Integer(id);
            System.out.println("Generated Id: " + generatedId);
            return generatedId;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) 
    throws MappingException {
    setTable_name(params.getProperty("table_name"));    }

//getters and setters    
}
```

the problem of this solution is the execution of select for each id so it seems generating load on the DBMS and its slow.
and the rs is looping twice for the first id ()
 any suggestion for  optimization is welcomed